# No module named found when installing Django

Tags: python, django

I used pip to install Django.

```
sudo pip install Django
```

It successfully works. However, when I tried to run python code.

```
import django
```

[image]
It shows No module found. And then I used pip freeze command to check the installation. Django is listed there!

```
pip freeze
Django==1.7
```

when I run which python, it shows:

```
which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

So can anyone help me out? My computer OS is MAC OS 10.9.2

Solution:
From one friends suggestion(running again-sudo pip install django), I found the result reminds me that the django already exist in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages. And then recalling the result of system path:

```
import path
for p in sys.path: print p
```

I didn't find that directory, then I used the code below:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

It also works in this way:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

But all these two work temporarily. If we close the terminal, we still need to add it again.

Comment: How does exactly the error traceback look? Thanks.

Comment: I just attached the picture. Now I guess if it is because there are many version of python in my computer. It isn't installed in right one.

Comment: I just checked the system path, there is no path name containing "Django" or "django"

Comment: pip install is not writing the module in a path accessible to python. this could be a python path problem or a pip one. could you post the output of `pip install django` ?

Comment: When running `pip install django` again, **it shows:Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...**

Comment: I found in my system path it is not included these path. Should I add it into system path permanently. It seems like the right way to solve it!

Comment: Yes, it works!! With the command:`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Please put down your solution as the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: don't use `pip` with `sudo`

Comment: @avi Why? Sometimes I found if I didn't add sudo, it would say permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution to all of your problems: [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)